# Rewrite, Redirect, and avoid duplicate content

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache2.2

I'm trying to redirect a single page using `.htaccess`. The actual file is `/abc.php`, I want it to appear as `/abc`. So these are my pseudo-rules:

- if the user hits /abc.php, rewrite the url as /abc
- if the user hits /abc, serve /abc.php

For SEO purposes, only one of `/abc` and `/abc.php` should be available.

My naive approach is this:

```
Redirect 301 /abc.php /abc
RewriteRule ^abcs$ /abc.php [NC,L]
```

This is causing infinite, looping redirects. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(abc)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(abc)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```